# add class to div and menu link, when link clicked is taking multiple clicks

Tags: javascript

I'm verrrrry out of practice with javascript. I'm sure there's a better way to write this overall, but this is what I've cobbled together. Right now I'm trying to make all the actions in this function to happen on click of an nav item. But, it seems to be taking 2 or 3 clicks to trigger each piece - i.e., 1 click to add class to nav item, 1 click to add class to hidden div.

This is a small nav menu attempting to change style on the clicked item (by adding/subtracting class) and shows/hides divs based on classes and IDs that match a custom tag in the nav link.

The JS

```
var tertiarylinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tertiarylink");
var tabsections = document.getElementsByClassName("tabsecion");

var myFunction = function () {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    // reset any links that had 'active'
    [].forEach.call(tertiarylinks, function (el) {
        el.classList.remove("active");
    });
    // close any tabs previously opened.
    [].forEach.call(tabsections, function (el) {
        el.classList.remove("active");
    });
    // now add 'active to clicked item
    event.target.classList.add('active');

    // show div matching clicked menu item 
    var tabsection = event.target.getAttribute("target");
    document.getElementById(tabsection).classList.add('active');
};

for (var i = 0; i < tertiarylinks.length; i++) {
    tertiarylinks[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

The html:

```
<nav class="nav-tertiary">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="tertiarylink active" id="link-overview" target="overview">
                        Overview
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="tertiarylink" id="link-link1" target="link1">
                        Link 1
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="tertiarylink" id="link-link2" target="link2">
                        Link two
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="overview" class="tabsection">
            <h2>Content section 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="link1" class="tabsection">
            <h2>Content section 2</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="link2" class="tabsection">
            <h2>Content section 3</h2>
        </div>
```

the css:

```
    .nav-tertiary ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        gap: 3rem;
        padding: 2rem 1rem;
     }

    .nav-tertiary ul li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        padding: 0 0 0.5rem;
        color: #242B31;
        font-weight: 700;
    }

    .nav-tertiary ul li a,
    .nav-tertiary ul li a:after {
        transition: all .5s;
    }

    .nav-tertiary ul li a.active,
    .nav-tertiary ul li a:active,
    .nav-tertiary ul li a:hover {
        color: #008AD8;
    }

        .nav-tertiary ul li a:after {
            display: block;
            content: "";
            float: left;
            background: #E4E6EA;
            width: 100%;
            height: 4px;
            border-radius: 6px;
            margin-top: 0.24rem;
        }

        .nav-tertiary ul li a.active:after,
        .nav-tertiary ul li a:hover:after,
        .nav-tertiary ul li a:active:after {
            background: #008AD8;
        }

    .tabsection {
        display: none;
    }

    .tabsection.active {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Hello, I hope I understood your meaning correctly
Do you want the line below to be lit when each link is clicked?